# formatted read from matlab using fscanf

Tags: string, matlab, file-io, formatting, scanf

I have a text file in the following format:

`Row: 001, rank: 6, max: 0.2431, index: 15.`

`Row: 002, rank: 10, max: 0.2331, index: 1.`

`Row: 003, rank: 110, max: 0.2330, index: 10.`

That is, the field `row` is padded with zeros so that the numbers have three digits. The field `max` is padded as well so that it has the fixed length. Neither `rank` nor `index` are padded.

[added after editting this post] Moreover, there are several lines of irrelevant text preceeding the data. The number of lines of irrelevant text is unknown. A line is formatted as above if and only if it is below the line: `DATA START BELOW`.

Is there any way to read the file using command

`[A, count] = fscanf(fid,['what is a proper format?'],[?, numberOfRows]);`

`A = A';` `B = A(:,[i,j,k,l]);`

such that `B=[1,6,0.2431,15; 2,10,0.2331,1; 3,110,0.2330,10;];`?

One way I know is `[A, count] = fscanf(fid,['%s %d, %s %d, %s %f, %s %d.'],[AnInstantNumberRelatedToTheLengthOfALine, numberOfRows]);` However, when new fields are appended to each line, this approach seems to lack of flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's one way:

```
s = importdata('file.txt'); %// read file as cell array of strings; one line per string
s = [s{:}]; %// concatenate into a single string
ind = regexp(s, 'DATA START BELOW', 'end'); %// locate line that marks start of data
s = s(ind+1:end); %// keep only data
s = regexp(s, '-?\d+\.?\d*', 'match'); %// extract numbers as a cell array of strings
s = str2double(s); %// convert to numbers 
s = reshape(s.', 4, []).'; %// reshape into four columns in row-mayor order
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I forgot to mention that there might be several lines (number of lines varies) before the data. All the data below the line `Data Start Here` are valid. Is there any way to handle it? I tried your method, but it shows "Cell contents reference from a non-cell array object." for command `s=[s{:}];`.

Comment: Please edit the example in the question to reflect the exact format of your file

Comment: Please see edited answer. I've added two lines to handle that

Answer (score 0):

Another answer:

```
fileID = fopen('mydata.txt');
C = textscan(fileID,'%s %f %s %f %s %f %s %f','delimiter',{',','Row:','max:','rank:','index:'});
fclose(fileID);
C = C(2:2:8);
```